# What happens after Azure App Service quota or limit is reached under the free tier?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-apps, azure-app-service-plans

I have an Azure API App hosted under free tier. I went through this article describing the limits and quotas. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#app-service-limits
I am not sure about the following scenario. What happens once the limit or quota is reached?

Will my API start returning 404 NOT FOUND or any particular message?

Comment: Which limit / quota are you referring to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What happens once the limit or quota is reached?

In [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2016/01/05/azure-web-apps-error-403-this-web-app-is-stopped/), we can know that if the Azure website has reached a resource quota limit that applies to either Free or Shared scale modes, the web app might stop working, and you would see "Error 403 - This web app is stopped" when browsing to your Azure website.

Comment: Does it restart automatically once after the new day starts?

Comment: The site that has reached a resource quota limit will be offline until the quota is reset.

Comment: ...and by default, no admin alerts are sent, so you never know when you exceed the limit and when your site is down... If you know how to set up an alert for a maxed out quota, please pitch in.

Comment: How to reset quota?

Answer (score 1):

Answering some of the comments, but doing it in an answer for clarity :

### FA restart

Yes Fa restart the next day at 00:00 (UTC) without needed to act.

### Quota reset

Having a paying subscription, I can increase the quota (not exactly the same as reseting it) during the day, in configuration, runtime settings. It might not be possible on a free tier of course.
[image]
Unfortunatly, it is not enough to enable the FA, and as far as I noticed, there is no GUI option to do it (a ticket was created in 2017 for it apparently). I found [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5056c4ac-1a12-44f7-96ba-0fc02e29ed30/reenabling-azure-function-after-quota-exceeded?forum=AzureFunctions) the powershell command to force enable your FA. I copy the script in case something happens to the source

```html
Login-AzureRmAccount
Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionId <Subscription Id>
$resourceProperties = @{
    "enabled"=$true
    };  
New-AzureRmResource -Location "<Location>" -Properties $resourceProperties -ResourceName "<Function App Name>" -ResourceType "Microsoft.Web/sites" -ResourceGroupName "<Resource Gruop Name>" -Force
```

### Alerting

Finally, regarding the alerting, we also worked on the issue. We worked on by creating an alert in 'monitor' with the following parameters.
[image]
This is a paying alert (10cents).
Note that in this case, I configured it so it fires when it reachs 70% of quota. Which is more efficient by allowing you to act before quota is reached

I'll review this post tomorrow (while I'll write the same documentation internally for my compagny ;))

Answer (score 0):

**In Quotas menu it mentioned**

> Applications hosted in a free or shared App Service plan are subject
>   to usage quotas. If any quota is exceeded the site will be stopped
>   until that quota resets. You can remove quotas on your app by scaling
>   up your App Service Plan. Learn more App Service plan/pricing tier: